# How to set the width of a child based on the height of it's parent view?

Tags: react-native

I would like to create a custom button component.

How can I specify the icon dimensions based on the button height?

```
<Pressable style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", borderWidth: 1, padding: 10}}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: "blue", width: ?, height: "50%"}} />
  <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Button</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `onLayout` attribute to get the height of the button:

```js
const [buttonHeight, setButtonHeight] = useState(some_initialValue)

<Pressable 
  style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", borderWidth: 1, padding: 10}}
  onLayout={(e)=>{setButtonHeight(e.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: "blue", width: buttonHeight*0.5, height: "50%"}} />
  <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Button</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the `nativeEvent` edit